# VNCViewer fonts

Tags: raspbian, vnc

I am trying to install tightvncserver on my Raspberry Pi.  After installation I attempt to start the vncserver `:1`, but I get font errors:

```
vncserver :1
Couldn't start Xtightvnc; trying default font path.
Please set correct fontPath in the vncserver script.
Couldn't start Xtightvnc process.

31/10/13 12:06:39 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.9
31/10/13 12:06:39 Copyright (C) 2000-2007 TightVNC Group
31/10/13 12:06:39 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
31/10/13 12:06:39 All Rights Reserved.
31/10/13 12:06:39 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
31/10/13 12:06:39 Desktop name 'X' (Raspberrypi-AES-rSDU-MPR:1)
31/10/13 12:06:39 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
31/10/13 12:06:39 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5901
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/' not found - ignoring
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/' not found - ignoring

Fatal server error:
could not open default font 'fixed'
31/10/13 12:06:40 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.9
31/10/13 12:06:40 Copyright (C) 2000-2007 TightVNC Group
31/10/13 12:06:40 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
31/10/13 12:06:40 All Rights Reserved.
31/10/13 12:06:40 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
31/10/13 12:06:40 Desktop name 'X' (Raspberrypi-AES-rSDU-MPR:1)
31/10/13 12:06:40 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
31/10/13 12:06:40 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5901
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/Speedo/' not found - ignoring
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/' not found - ignoring
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/' not found - ignoring

Fatal server error:
could not open default font 'fixed'
```

Comment: and your question is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into the same problem today and I could get rid of some of the warnings by installing the two packages:

```
sudo apt-get install xfonts-75dpi
sudo apt-get install xfonts-100dpi
```

**Update**

I got it working using `x11vnc` rather than `tightvncserver` or `vncserver`

1. [This post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=39722&p=326695) set me on track. So first I connect to my PI using ssh

   ```
   ssh pi@rasperrypi
   ```
2. Install `x11vnc`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install x11vnc
   ```
3. Start the X and then start x11vnc

   ```
   startx &
   x11vnc &
   ```
4. Now on my Mac I open the Finder and hit `CMD + K` and connect to my raspberrypi using `vnc://raspberrypi`

   [image]
5. Voila

   [image]

Comment: I just installed Xtightvnc, on jessie.  This include installing xfonts-base.  However there was an error about missing the 75dpi fonts.  I reinstalled xfonts-base as described in another answer here, still no 75dpi fonts.  So indeed I needed to apt-get install them separately as described here, to get rid of the error.  It would appear that xfonts-base no long includes 75dpi but tightvnc requires it.

Answer (score 6):

The fonts are missing because the `xfonts-base` package is not installed on your server. Install it with

```
sudo apt-get install xfonts-base
```

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here (including why this will work), and provide a link for reference.

Comment: You should explain why the OP should install `xfonts-base`. Right now your answer is going to get closed for being too vague/no explanation.

Comment: what's not to understand here? "I get font errors" -- "install xfonts-base", simple as that.

Comment: Very clear, concise without chit-chat. This is actually solved the issue for me when using `tightvncserver` and getting the `could not open default font 'fixed'` message

Answer (score 1):

I received the fontpath error when I copy and pasted bad text into the CLI.
eg:

```
vncserver :1 -geometry 1264x684 -depth 24 [+ other crud here]
```

stripping it down to the correct command fixed it

```
vncserver :1 -geometry 1264x684 -depth 24
```